# How to view json data from angularjs http callback?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I can see my json data in the console and I want to view it on html page after clickbutton function.  From my understaning I can either do a promise ($q) or then with http or ngResource. First I want to do http then migrate to ngResource.  For some reason my scope is still undefined. Maybe it's a ng-init or ng-repeat I'm missing?  Any ideas?

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.factory('httpq', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    get: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.get.apply(null, arguments)
      .success(deferred.resolve)
      .error(deferred.resolve);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
});

  app.controller('myController', function($scope, httpq) {

  httpq.get('http://localhost:8080/states')
  .then(function(data) {
    $scope.returnedData = data;
  })

  $scope.clickButton = function() {
      $scope.returnedData;
}

});
```

**view**

```
   <div data-ng-controller="myController">
        <button data-ng-click="clickButton()">Get Data From Server</button>
        <p>JSON Data : {{returnedData}}</p> 

    </div>
```

Comment: i will advice you to go with the ajax service in angualr.

Comment: you know how to accept answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

> Use Ajax call

**Service**:

```
var demoService = angular.module('demoService', [])
.service('myService',['$http', function($http) {

    this.getdata = function(entity){
        var promise = $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'services/entity/add',
            data : entity,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            cache : false
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response;
        });
        return promise;     
    };
}]);
```

**Controller :**

```
var demoService = angular.module('demoService', [])
.controller('myctr',['$scope','myService',function($scope,myService){
   myService.getdata().then(function(response){
            //Success

        },function(response){

            //Error         
        });

}]);
```

now you can see your json in controller **success**

Comment: you can also use .factory instead of .service its just an working example for you :D

Answer (score 1):

$http itself is a promise, no need to create a new promise. Just return the $http.get wihoit the success written there and right the sucess fn in the controller itself. So your code will look like this:

```
app.factory('httpq', function($http) {
   return {
       get: function() {
          return $http.get.apply(null, arguments);
       }
   }
});
```

Your controller:

```
app.controller('myController',  function($scope, httpq) {
      httpq.get('http://localhost:8080/states').then(function(data) {
   $scope.returnedData = data;
 })

  $scope.clickButton = function() {
      $scope.returnedData;
  }

 });
```

Comment: Thanks V.  That works.  Quick question.  When someone gives a solution to your problem am I supposed to answer my own question?  Is there a way to mark the question as complete?

Comment: Yes there is a tick mark against the answer on the left just click it

Comment: If you're talking about the up and down arrows, my reputation isn't high enough yet.  Guess I have to wait?  Thanks.  I have to read stackoverflow's rules.  Maybe find some basic java questions to answer first.

Comment: You can mark this answer as accepted with clicking the tick besides this answer below the arrow

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$scope.returnedData=JSON.parse(data);
```

It will give you values in JSON  format

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with *promise*. But your factory code seems to be ok.

In controller declare your object first.

If it's just object declare it as

```
$scope.returnedData = {};
```

If it's array, declare it as

```
$scope.returnedData = [];
```

The the object will not be undefined and changes will affect in HTML