# Angular scoping weirdness in directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a custom directive that looks like this:

```
<menu-section sections="menu.sections" addons="addons"
    options="options" menu="menu.id"></menu-section>
```

I've defined it here like this:

```
adminApp.directive("menuSection", ["$addons", function($addons) {

    var sectionController = function($scope) {
        console.log($scope);
        console.log($scope.sections);

        // Some $scope level functions defined here.
    };

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            sections: "=",
            options: "=",
            menu: "=",
            addons: "="
        },
        controller: sectionController,
        templateUrl: "/template/menus/menu-section.html"
    }
}]);
```

In the template I have a select element.

```
<div ng-repeat="section in sections">
  <select ng-model="section.current_addon_ids" ng-options="addon.id as addon.name for addon in addons track by addon.id"></select>
```

My problem is that the current_addon_ids doesn't seem to be set. The select is filling up fine but current_addon_ids is undefined.  In the console.logs above $scope returns a sections array. However, the next line returns an "undefined" to the console.

Is there some kind of weird timing issue going on here?  It seems completely bizarre that I can see the section array in the $scope variable in one statement but in the next it is undefined.

**Update:**

I've figured out what is going on. Just not sure how to fix it.

In the Page Controller, the Menu is being set by getting a JSON structure from an Ajax call. That is where the Sections are being set on the Menu. However, the Directive Controller is running before the Ajax call comes back with a response. So when I attempt to access that property it is undefined.

Comment: i dont see any mistake in your code , I think in link function also its returning undefined ? . could you please make a fiddle of plunker to reproduce it

Comment: i think its an parent scope try this statement  $scope.$parent.sections

Comment: I updated the original post. Still figuring out how to fix the problem.

Comment: @AndrewCooper so in previous question you not mentioned you are using ajax so not as you say you are using ajax so you have to use promise pattern see this answer   http://stackoverflow.com/a/30505788/4696809  it will help you

Comment: @KevalBhatt Thanks! That was indeed helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went with was to re-evaluate whether I had put too much into a single directive. I removed this directive and made several smaller ones. In the parent scope I could then use async.series() and collect the bits of the remote data in a bit more controlled way.

Thanks for the comments and helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As per your updated question, I think you can use `ng-if` for your custom directive when the ajax is returned successfully you can make it show . Though i'm unaware of your page controller whether your using service/factory for ajax below would be similar.

**Template**

```
 <menu-section ng-if="" sections="menu.sections" addons="addons"
    options="options" menu="menu.id"></menu-section>
```

**controller**

```
app.controller('pageController',['$scope','ajaxService',function($scope,ajaxService){

        $scope.sections = [];
        $scope.showMenuDirective = false; // initially directive is not shown


 //get data or $http here itself , i thought u have use some service to do this

    ajaxService.getData.then(function(data){
           $scope.sections.push(data);
           $scope.showMenuDirective = true; // directive shown here on success
        });

  }]);
```

Comment: I found this answer informative.  I'm not using this solution but it certainly will be in my brain for future reference.  Thanks.